# Parsing XML File that has same attributes inside node

Tags: java, xml

I have XML file which contains information about Coronavirus pandemic like this

```
    <records>
<record>
<dateRep>18/05/2020</dateRep>
<day>18</day>
<month>5</month>
<year>2020</year>
<cases>262</cases>
<deaths>1</deaths>
<countriesAndTerritories>Afghanistan</countriesAndTerritories>
<geoId>AF</geoId>
<countryterritoryCode>AFG</countryterritoryCode>
<popData2018>37172386</popData2018>
<continentExp>Asia</continentExp>
</record>

<record>
<dateRep>17/05/2020</dateRep>
<day>17</day>
<month>5</month>
<year>2020</year>
<cases>0</cases>
<deaths>0</deaths>
<countriesAndTerritories>Afghanistan</countriesAndTerritories>
<geoId>AF</geoId>
<countryterritoryCode>AFG</countryterritoryCode>
<popData2018>37172386</popData2018>
<continentExp>Asia</continentExp>
</record>

<record>
<dateRep>17/05/2020</dateRep>
<day>17</day>
<month>5</month>
<year>2020</year>
<cases>0</cases>
<deaths>0</deaths>
<countriesAndTerritories>Turkey</countriesAndTerritories>
<geoId>TR</geoId>
<countryterritoryCode>TRY</countryterritoryCode>
<popData2018>80172310</popData2018>
<continentExp>asia</continentExp>
</record>
```

as you see this XML data contain data about the same country (AFGHANISTAN)
I need to go through this XML file and get  all nodes which has same countriesAndTerritories attribute 
so for Afghanistan, for example, I want to add all cases that every node has so I can get total Cases from all nodes 
this is my code to parse the file

```
 String filePath = "data.xml";
        File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
            //now XML is loaded as Document in memory, lets convert it to Object List
            List<Corona> empList = new ArrayList<Corona>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("geoId");

                   Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
               System.out.println("CurrentNode"+currentNode.getChildNodes());
                empList.add(getCorona(nodeList.item(i)));
            }
```

I wish I explained my problem clearly, I just want to go on through the XML file and  get all nodes that have same countriesAndTerritories attribute

Answer (score 0):

For the XML parser each main node must be unique and it is not the case in your XML file: the record node. You could do as following

```
<record id="1">
<dateRep>18/05/2020</dateRep>
<day>18</day>
<month>5</month>
<year>2020</year>
<cases>262</cases>
<deaths>1</deaths>
<countriesAndTerritories>Afghanistan</countriesAndTerritories>
<geoId>AF</geoId>
<countryterritoryCode>AFG</countryterritoryCode>
<popData2018>37172386</popData2018>
<continentExp>Asia</continentExp>
</record>

<record id="2">
<dateRep>17/05/2020</dateRep>
<day>17</day>
<month>5</month>
<year>2020</year>
<cases>0</cases>
<deaths>0</deaths>
<countriesAndTerritories>Afghanistan</countriesAndTerritories>
<geoId>AF</geoId>
<countryterritoryCode>AFG</countryterritoryCode>
<popData2018>37172386</popData2018>
<continentExp>Asia</continentExp>
</record>
 ...
```

Comment: thank you for  your reply, but actually I am not making this XML File I am fetching it from this link https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/xml/   so I can not change it  , I Just want to go through the xml file to add all cases attributes that is related to one country to get  total cases

Comment: wherever the data come from they are incomplete.